# Typescript not working with tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

On running tsc --watch with tsconfig in project I am getting the error below.
It requires types for react and redux in node js.

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'abstract-leveldown'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'abstract-leveldown'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'bn.js'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'bn.js'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'body-parser'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'body-parser'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'connect'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'connect'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'debug'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'debug'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'express'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express-jwt'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'express-jwt'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express-serve-static-core'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'express-serve-static-core'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'express-unless'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'express-unless'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'firebase'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'firebase'

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'graceful-fs'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'graceful-fs'
```

Please explain why this is happening.
Do I have set up the project in [Github](https://github.com/AyushDocs/stackoverflow-question).

Comment: Your GitHub code works just fine on my system, Can you please share your error details.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i added the actual stack trace

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled node js and npm and reinstalled and still had the same problem. Then I noticed there was an npm and npm-cache folder and node_modules folder which uninstalling does not remove. When I removed them and reinstalled node voila! my code started working. My bet is that node_modules was probably guilty.

Comment: I just closed my IDE which is vs code uninstalled and installed my node modules and started vs code again and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I switched branches but forgot to reinstall npm packages. So do:

`npm install` in the current branch and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I re-cloned my project. You need to install the node_modules folder since it isn't committed to the repository.

Do `npm install` in the directory that has the tsconfig.json file.

If the error still shows, restart your IDE, problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

in my case similar error was produced by inner dependencies of one of the packages. I just searched `PACKAGE_NAME` inside package-lock.json to figure out which package includes that bad `PACKAGE_NAME` package and after that upgraded the package I found to the latest version.
(Where `PACKAGE_NAME` is the name of the package from the error).
maybe this will be helpful to somebody as I get in this question searching for the solution.