# Typescript: Graphql code generator cannot generate types - plugin_helpers_1.DetailedError is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am having trouble generating types with graphql code-gen.

When I try running the generator, I get an error that says:

> Generate outputs   ❯ Generate to src/lib/graphql.tsx
> ✔ Load GraphQL schemas
> ✔ Load GraphQL documents
> ✖ plugin_helpers_1.DetailedError is not a constructor

In my vscode, a problem is identified as follows:

> ```
> Cannot find type definition file for 'express-unless'.
>   The file is in the program because:
>     Entry point for implicit type library 'express-unless'
> ```

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552292/typescript-not-working-with-tsconfig-json) and have tried deleting my node_modules and yarn.lock and re-installing. I get the same error message and vscode problem when I tried.

I don not know what either of these error messages is trying to communicate. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

My tsconfig has:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "lib/*": [
        "lib/*"
      ]
    },
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you show your codegen.yml?